# Stop an action in C# or change it to thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, action

I have the following code:

```
void ThreadMethod()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Thread..");
}

IAsyncResult actionResult;

Action a = new Action();
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));

actionResult = a.BeginInvoke(ActionCompleted, null);
t.Start();

void ActionCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   if (ar.IsCompleted)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Action finished");
      t.Abort();
   }
}
```

How can I stop the action manually?
For example

```
if (actionShouldBeStopped)
{
   action.Stop(); // and ActionComplete should be run.
}
```

Another option is to change the Action to Thread, but then how should it look like? How can I implement something like ActionCompleted for Thread?

Thanks,
Maestro

Comment: See [this SO thread: lock and listen to CancellationToken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7416786/485076) perhaps you'll find something helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch your implementation from `Thread` to [the BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), it supports cancellation (i.e. stopping the thread), progress report and has an event for when the thread is done (`RunWorkerCompleted` event)